# jquery timepicker addon onDone

Tags: jquery, datepicker, add-on, timepicker

I found this.
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-done-button-onclick
I try to use this with the timepicker addon (http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/19/timepicker-addon-for-jquery-ui-datepicker), but it doesnt work. 
Does anyone have an idea, how to get it to work?
Regards

Comment: Marking questions you ask, as answered (by checking the little checkbox by the most helpful answer)

Answer (score 0):

use this **onClose** function:

```
onClose: function() {

      function isDonePressed(){
            return ($('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1);   
      }

       if (isDonePressed()){

            //do your job

      }

 }
```